# Images for controller buttons and keyboard keys

Tags: discussion, images

I just saw [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/building-a-stairwell-down-multiple-levels-in-dwarf-fortress/1270#1270) and was kicking myself for not thinking of this first, but I think it's a fantastic idea to use images for keyboard keys and console buttons.  Can we get or does there already exist a web resource that has buttons for all the various buttons for game controllers and keyboard keys?

I think if we started using these types of images across the board when discussing button combos it would really make the website look great.

Answer (score 27):

combining the `<kbd>` tag with unicode and html entities can give some great results.

Directional arrows:

- <kbd>↑</kbd> `<kbd>&uarr;</kbd>`
- <kbd>↓</kbd> `<kbd>&darr;</kbd>`
- <kbd>←</kbd> `<kbd>&larr;</kbd>`
- <kbd>→</kbd> `<kbd>&rarr;</kbd>`

Basic Buttons + Analog stick:

- Ⓐ `&#x24B6;`
- Ⓑ `&#x24B7;`
- Ⓒ `&#x24B8;`
- Ⓛ `&#x24C1;`
- Ⓞ `&#x24C4;`
- Ⓡ `&#x24C7;`
- Ⓤ `&#x24CA;`
- Ⓧ `&#x24CD;`
- Ⓨ `&#x24CE;`
- Ⓩ `&#x24CF;`
- ⓐ `&#x24D0;`
- ⓑ `&#x24D1;`
- ⓒ `&#x24D2;`
- ⓧ `&#x24E7;`
- ⓨ `&#x24E8;`
- ⓩ `&#x24E9;`
- △ `&#x25B3;`
- ○ `&#x25CB;`
- ✕ `&#x2715;`
- □ `&#x25A1;`
- ① `&#x2460;`
- ② `&#x2461;`
- ◉ `&#x25C9;`

Shoulder + Other Buttons

- <kbd>L</kbd> `<kbd>L</kbd>`
- <kbd>R</kbd> `<kbd>R</kbd>`
- <kbd>L1</kbd> `<kbd>L1</kbd>`
- <kbd>L2</kbd> `<kbd>L2</kbd>`
- <kbd>R1</kbd> `<kbd>R1</kbd>`
- <kbd>R2</kbd> `<kbd>R2</kbd>`
- <kbd>+</kbd> `<kbd>+</kbd>`
- <kbd>-</kbd> `<kbd>-</kbd>`
- <kbd>home</kbd> `<kbd>home</kbd>`
- <kbd>options</kbd> `<kbd>options</kbd>`
- <kbd>select</kbd> `<kbd>select</kbd>`
- <kbd>share</kbd> `<kbd>share</kbd>`
- <kbd>start</kbd> `<kbd>start</kbd>`

So remember: <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>ⒷⒶ<kbd>start</kbd>

Comment: With Ouya out now, needs a U

Comment: added both the Capital O & U for OUYA and the options & share for PS4

Answer (score 12):

You can already do this using the `<kbd>` HTML tag, like so..

<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

```
<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>
```

and, you can use HTML entities for up down and so forth.

<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>

```
<kbd>&uarr;</kbd> <kbd>&darr;</kbd> <kbd>&larr;</kbd> <kbd>&rarr;</kbd>
```

List of HTML entities:
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/entities.html

Comment: Sweet, that takes care of the keyboard and directional buttons/d-pads.  Now we just need console specific images.

Comment: @cowgod You could get away with some combination of this and unicode (○, △, ◻), though they aren't coloured. They do work with <kbd> elements, though.

Comment: @cowgod Not sure about it, but Playstation button images are registered by Sony. Maybe is better to avoid images and use only characters.

Comment: I was wondering how people made the button-esque characters.

Comment: There should be shorthand syntax for this; who wants to memorize entities for arrows and shapes?

Comment: There's another issue with this answer: Those of us reading on Macs (or at least in Firefox on a Mac) may be unable to see three of those arrows -- up, down and left. Only right arrow is rendering for me.

Comment: I see everything in Safari 4 and 5 for Mac.

Comment: @Corey -- just map them into your keyboard layout!

Answer (score 8):

Symbols for your copy pasting needs:

## <kbd>`△`</kbd> <kbd>`◯`</kbd> <kbd>`✕`</kbd> <kbd>□</kbd> <kbd>`▷`</kbd>

## <kbd>`←`</kbd> <kbd>`↑`</kbd> <kbd>`↓`</kbd> <kbd>`→`</kbd>

## <kbd>↖</kbd> <kbd>`↹`</kbd> <kbd>`↲`</kbd> <kbd>⟵</kbd> <kbd>`̲↓`</kbd>

## <kbd>⊞</kbd> <kbd>`␣`</kbd> <kbd>␛</kbd> <kbd>␡</kbd>

## <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>`⌥`</kbd> <kbd>`⎋`</kbd> <kbd>⌫</kbd> <kbd>⇪</kbd>

Don't go too overboard with these, however, as they may not display correctly everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's a great idea. For now:

D-pad: <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>

Buttons: <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>home</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>start</kbd> <kbd>select</kbd> <kbd>[insert shape name]</kbd>

Triggers: <kbd>-L-</kbd> <kbd>-R-</kbd> <kbd>-L1-</kbd> <kbd>-L2-</kbd> <kbd>-R1-</kbd> <kbd>-R2-</kbd>

Analog Sticks: (o) (L) (R)

`< kbd > text < /kbd >` for the buttons-like appearance.

Edit: There are many ways to display these, but there should be a non-technical user friendly way to input them.

Comment: It would be nice if we could get console specific images too, such as the triangle, square, etc. for the Playstation, and X, Y, B and A for the XBox.  Not putting that on you, just saying.  This is a great start!

Comment: Why wouldn't <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> etc work?

Comment: They do work; I was unaware of that HTML at the time of writing this answer. I'll go and edit.

Comment: We should not use those for the D-pad. Use &uarr; ↑, &darr; ↓, &larr; ←, and &rarr; →.

Comment: @CyberSkull Agreed – I wasn't that Unicode-savy back when I wrote this answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

No one asked but:

### Mouse Buttons:

| Icon (`<kbd>![image]</kbd>`) | Image link |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPwD4.png |
| <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwrAW.png |
| <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/OASpJ.png |
| <kbd>MW [image: MW]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1vyT.png |

This is copied from [this answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1128/65455) posted by user [Gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) on Blender Meta.

I added buttons for the Mouse Wheel up and down scroll motions (also from the (old) [Blender Wiki](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Meta:Guides/Templates/), but with the MWD icon slightly changed for improved visibility and consistency):

| Icon (`<kbd>![image]</kbd>`) | Image link |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>MWU [image: MWU]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vtba.png |
| <kbd>MWD [image: MWD]</kbd> | https://i.stack.imgur.com/doOIR.png |

---

I'd also suggest installing the script linked there (and [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/65455)) as it makes creating `<kbd>` notations a lot easier (although, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, it interferes with the 'Undo' functionality of Markdown, but the script can easily be edited in Tampermonkey, and I bound it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).
I have quickly forked it [here](https://gist.github.com/protagnost/c3b8911da578ee1bb8eca8e6f51bde88), with the added support for Mouse Wheel up and down movements (and some extra changes).

Answer (score 2):

I've [said this before elsewhere](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/feature-request-add-editor-buttons-for-symbols-common-to-the-subject), but we really need a symbol palette. It would greatly simplify typing in something like the <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Ⓑ</kbd><kbd>Ⓐ</kbd><kbd>[Select]</kbd><kbd>Start</kbd> Konami Code, for example.