# How do i use formatting to make pretty key combinations?

Tags: support, design, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Images for controller buttons and keyboard keys](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/images-for-controller-buttons-and-keyboard-keys)

At one time, I saw someone reply to a question about key combinations with an answer that used markdown to actually show the key combinations on little key graphics.

I'm trying to duplicate that effect on my answer to this question:
[In Payday: The Heist, how do you change which upgrade tree you're on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33263/5398)
and I can't find anything in the reference guide to tell me how to create that formatting.

Of course, I also can't find the original question.  ):

**How do you format text to show key combinations as actual keys?**

Comment: This pretty much answers your question: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316/images-for-controller-buttons-and-keyboard-keys

Comment: @mordi2k - I searched, but that question did not show in the results.  Thanks!  I'll mark this question as dupe.

Comment: It's not really a dupe, but if you're okay with it...

Answer (score 0):

`<kbd>please don't abuse, or things get ugly really fast</kbd>`